# SQL Server sum column base on id

Tags: sql-server, sum, sql-server-2014

I have table and I want result like this:

```
id      ItemId      Quantity   Sum
 1         1            2       2
 2         1            1       3
 3         1            1       4
 4         2            3       3
 4         2            1       4
 5         3            6       6
```

where `id` is primary key and `ItemId` is foreign key and `Quantity` is integer column.

I want that "sum" column sum quantity base on `itemId`.
I used group by but it does not give me what I want. With group by
I get this result:

```
id      ItemId      Quantity    Sum
 1         1            2        4
 2         1            1        4
 3         1            1        4
 .         .            .        .
 .         .            .        .
```

The "sum" column is same for all related rows.

I also used this code:

```
select it1.id, it1.ItemId, it1.Quantity ,

(select sum(it2.Quantity) from InventoryTransactions it2 where it2.ItemId = it1.ItemId and it2.id <= it1.Id) as Sum

 from InventoryTransactions it1
 order by it1.ItemId , it1.Id
```

This code gives me what I want but it takes too long for a large number of records, for example for one million records. It takes more than two minute to execute

What is the best way?

Comment: What sql server version?

Comment: sql server 2014

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In sql server >= 2012 you can do a rolling sum easier

```
select it1.id, it1.ItemId, it1.Quantity,
sum(Quantity) over(partition by itemid order by Id rows unbounded preceding) as Sum
from InventoryTransactions it1
 order by it1.ItemId , it1.Id
```

Comment: Did you mean SQL Server **>=** 2012?

Comment: @TT. I forgot this is an IT site and have to be precise :)

Comment: Nps, I'm a bit of a nit-picker ;)